# couldn't find file 'owl.theme' with type 'text/css', Rails 6

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sprockets, webpacker

I have installed gem 'owlcarousel-rails' on Rails 6 but get the error message: couldn't find file 'owl.theme' with type 'text/css'. Thanks if anyone is able to help!
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfTe2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add error message to the question itself - as text, so it's easier for others to search.

Seeing code how you are trying to get that `owl.theme` would also be splendid.

Also, I'm not a rubyist, but are you sure that `owlcarousel-rails` provides `owl.theme`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm simply added the owl.theme.default.css file into the stylesheets folder of my Rails project.

The themes are available on the Github page of the Gem:
https://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets